# Get the title of the panel using id

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a Ext Js panel and I want to get the Title of the panel for some purpose.

I have the id of the panel and I need to get the title of the panel from it.

I am looking for some thing like this

```
Ext.getCmp('myPanel').getTitle();
```

I am using Ext Js 3.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no `getTitle()` method is defined for the component `Ext.Panel`, I would go for the *property* directly:

```
var myTitle = Ext.getCmp('myPanel').title;
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Is it true for any property then ? For e.g., will Ext.getCmp('myCheckBox').value work ? How do we differentiate ?

Comment: I believe that the best practice would be to use any provided methods to get access to the various properties. If a method is not available, then you could extend the component in question to provide a method, or if you just want to access the property, then get it like with the title :) There is nothing wrong with accessing the properties directly. Use a tool like *FireBug* to inspect the various properties and methods.